# What is the smallest integer with 100 non trivial factors?

Tags: number-theory, optimization, factoring

Excluding 1 and itself as factors, what is the smallest integer with 100 different factor values?

Example: 20 has 4 non trivial factors (2*10 and 4*5)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! It is generally a rule of thumb here to show any attempts you made on the problem or where you got stuck, as an alternative to just asking for the answer.

Comment: Probably $2^63^45^2=129600$, not sure.

Comment: Do you want at least 100 different factors or exactly 100 different factors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you mean "exactly $100$ non-trivial divisors".

If the natural number $n>1$ has prime decomposition $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$, the total number of factors is $$d(n)=\prod (a_i+1)$$

As you wish to exclude $1$ and $n$, you are interested in $F(n)=d(n)-2$.  We see that you are requiring $F(n)=100$ or, equivalently, $d(n)=102$

Now, $102=2\times 3\times 17$.  We therefore seek $\{a_i\}$ with $\prod (a_i+1)=2\times 3\times 17$.  We remark that our $n$ can not have more than three prime divisors.

Case I:  One prime.  Then the best we can do is $n=2^{101}$ which seems unlikely to be minimal.

Case II.  Two primes  Then the best we can do is $2^{16}3^5$, certainly a lot better than $2^{101}$

Case III. Three primes.  Now the best we can do is $2^{16}3^25$, which is only $\boxed {2949120}$.

Comment: Thank you! Concise, to the point and nothing extra.

Answer (score 3):

This can be found with OEIS entry [A061799](https://oeis.org/A061799/), for which $a_n$ is the smallest number with *at least* $n$ divisors. Your definition excludes 1 and the number itself, so we're looking for $a_{102}$ which is **50400**.

Alternatively, use OEIS entry [A005179](https://oeis.org/A005179/), for which $a_n$ is the smallest number with *exactly* $n$ divisors. In this case $a_{102}$ is 2949120.

Comment: in The Martian with Matt Damon, when they call the rescue plan Project Elrond, the head of NASA says he wants his code name to be Glorfindel

Answer (score -1):

If it has to be 100 different prime factors, the 10 year olds in my class looked at the pattern of answers starting at 1 prime factor, 2,3,4, 5,6 etc and the size of the numbers (powers of $10$). We decided that as a minimum the answer must have at least $98$ zeros.

Comment: The product of the first 100 primes is 4711930799906184953162487834760260422020574773409675520188634839616415335845034221205289256705544681972439104097777157991804380284218315038719444943990492579030720635990538452312528339864352999310398481791730017201031090 which has only 28 zeros. You can probably get at least slightly lower by using different primes.